# Kotlin - NoSuchMethodError while instantiating Throwable

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Trying to instantiate objects of `Throwable` throws the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;ILkotlin/jvm/internal/DefaultConstructorMarker;)V in class Ljava/lang/Throwable; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.Throwable' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
```

Different ways I tried are:

```
val s = Throwable()
val t = Throwable("This is a message")
```

Some things I observed (using Android Studio on a Mac):

- "Command + click"ing on `Throwable` while in Java classes takes me to `java.lang.Throwable` whereas from a Kotlin class, it takes me to the `Throwable` definition in `Throwable.kt`
- I tried using `val s = java.lang.Throwable()` but it wouldn't even compile

I am using Kotlin version `1.0.0-beta-2423`

Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: How about your try **java.lang.Throwable s = new java.lang.Throwable();**

Comment: It wouldn't compile as it is not valid kotlin

Comment: see the answer, you needed to pass string as well as a null (which I believe is the cause).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPD: the bug is fixed, the problem should no longer be reproducible.

This is a bug in Kotlin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5910. As a workaround, pass both arguments to `Throwable`'s constructor.

Comment: I see this has been fixed in Beta 4 (at least it doesn't crash for me anymore). If it is correct, can you please update the status in youtrack?

Comment: @x-treme The YT issue is marked as Fixed since 17 Dec 2015

Comment: I thought that some kind of info will be entered into the tracker which says which version carries the fix (would "fix version" be the field for that?)

Answer (score 1):

First time I come across `kotlin` interesting, at first look I thought you are mixing javascript and java but, not really.

I looked up the docs for kotlin, specially for [Throwable](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-throwable/) and interestingly there constructor is as follow:

```
Throwable(message: String? = null, cause: Throwable? = null)
```

And then I looked up how to initialize objects in Kotlin, scary. And found this great [place](http://blog.omalley.id.au/2013/07/27/null-handling-in-kotlin.html) shows how to declare objects and handle null values. I declared the Throwable as follow:

```
//last arg as null - which is the cause
var a : Throwable =  Throwable("I am Throwable - Kotlin vesion.", null)
```

That worked without any error when I tried it in online kotlin [compiler/interpretor](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Hello,%20world!/Simplest%20version/Simplest%20version.kt) then I printed it as follow:

```
 print(a)
 print(a.printStackTrace())
```

And I got the following output:

```
java.lang.Throwable: I am Throwable - Kotlin vesion.
```

Followed by result of printStackTrace() as shown below:

```
java.lang.Throwable: I am Throwable - Kotlin vesion.
    at Simplest_versionKt.main(Simplest version.kt:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jetbrains.webdemo.executors.JavaExecutor.main(JavaExecutor.java:46)
kotlin.Unit
```

Comment: `Throwable("test", null)` does work whereas `Throwable("test")` and `Throwable()` don't !!  Confusing..

Comment: I guess Kotlin always want to have a cause for a Throwable even if its null.